# Subnet mask returned from WMI not accepted in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, wmi, ipv6

In a inventory sotware I use WMI to get informations from machines.

My query:

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration
```

For every machine I save ip addresses in a database, getting values from **IPAddress** and **IPSubnet** fields. For some servers everything works ok, for bot ipv4 and ipv6 addresses.

On some Windows 2008r2 server I have a problem with the **Microsoft Failover Cluster Virtual Adapter** interface. It has a ipv6 address. Fine. But as subnet mask it give me the string: 64

When I try to use it in my postgresql function I have the error:

```
ERROR: invalid input syntax for type inet: "64"
```

Is 64 a valid ipv6 subnet mask?

If yes, why postgresql does not accept it? How can I workaround this problem?

If not, how can I workaround this problem?

Version involved:

- Microsoft Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise SP1
- Postgresql 9.3 (on linux)
- .net framework 4 (but I think it is irrilevant in this case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/64` is a valid subnet mask (well-known a prefix length, technically) for an IPv6 address. Based on your error message the problem is that you're not putting an address plus subnet mask in the `inet` field but only the prefix length.

I get the feeling that you are using the `inet` type in the wrong way. An `inet` field contains an address and subnet mask (prefix length) in one field. You don't need to create separate columns for address and mask.

You'll have to convert the subnet mask to a prefix length though. The prefix length is the number of consecutive bits from the start set to 1 in the binary representation of the address. For example `255.255.255.0` corresponds to prefix length 24: each part of an IPv4 address is 8 bits and 255 corresponds to eight bits set to 1. So you get 3x8=24. Subnet mask`255.255.128.0` corresponds to prefix length 17 etc.

IPv6 only uses the prefix length (called CIDR) notation. For IPv4 both netmask and CIDR notation are commonly used, but PostgreSQL only supports CIDR notation. Which is ok because it is far simpler to use ☺

The way CIDR notation works is: you write the address, then a slash followed by the prefix length. So you would store address `192.0.2.123` with netmask `255.255.255.0` as `192.0.2.123/24` in a single `inet` field. An IPv6 address with prefix length would look like `2001:db8:aaa:bbb::1/64`.

Comment: You are right. I will use just a field for both address and mask. I made a mistake. Anyway I find annoying the way WMI returns results :-)
I digged deeper here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/datatype-net-types.html